# Iterating through a list with beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
players = ['a','b','c',etc]    
list = []
for player in players:
    html = 'https://hoopshype.com/player/'+player+'/salary/'
    webpage = requests.get(html)
    content = webpage.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    table = soup.find('table',{'class':'player-payroll-1'})
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        for item in row.find_all('td',{'class':'table-value'}):
            a = item.text
            c = a.replace("\n","").replace("\t","")
            b.append(c)
```

I am trying to iterated through a large list of players.  Now, I know my code is correct, as I've checked it specifically with a few players with success.

But when I try it over the entire list, the for loop stops and I get the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I am looking to find out how to execute the for loop to:

a) find out exactly which items in my list are causing the error and
b) continue iterating through the list despite the errors

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: put a `print (player)` right at the beginning of your loop to see at which point it throws the error. Any reason you need to go through a list when the whole table of players is available on 1 call?

Comment: wow.  didn't even see that page.  thanks!

Comment: oh ok. Ya wasn't sure if you needed something that was additional in the player page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get through errors you can use `try` and `except`. But it seems unnecessary to iterate to each player page just to get the salary when you get it in the initial table. Any particular reason you need to make a call to EACH player page?

Here's the whole table in one go:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://hoopshype.com/salaries/players/')[0]
```

**Output of 1st 10 rows:**

```
print (df.head(10).to_string())
   Unnamed: 0             Player      2019/20      2020/21      2021/22      2022/23 2023/24 2024/25
0         1.0      Stephen Curry  $40,231,758  $43,006,362  $45,780,966           $0      $0      $0
1         2.0  Russell Westbrook  $38,506,482  $41,358,814  $44,211,146  $47,063,478      $0      $0
2         2.0         Chris Paul  $38,506,482  $41,358,814  $44,211,146           $0      $0      $0
3         4.0       James Harden  $38,199,000  $41,254,920  $44,310,840  $47,366,760      $0      $0
4         4.0          John Wall  $38,199,000  $41,254,920  $44,310,840  $47,366,760      $0      $0
5         6.0       LeBron James  $37,436,858  $39,219,566  $41,002,274           $0      $0      $0
6         7.0       Kevin Durant  $37,199,000  $39,058,950  $40,918,900  $42,778,850      $0      $0
7         8.0      Blake Griffin  $34,449,964  $36,810,996  $38,957,028           $0      $0      $0
8         9.0         Kyle Lowry  $33,296,296  $30,500,000           $0           $0      $0      $0
9        10.0        Paul George  $33,005,556  $35,450,412  $37,895,268           $0      $0      $0
```